# play2 java form binding - how to set field name to map to object?

Tags: forms, playframework-2.0

Say I have the below test case

I want to be able to bind camel case parameters:

```
anyData.put("my_id", "bob@gmail.com");
```

How can I get this test to pass??

```
public class FormBindingExampleTest {

    public static class FormBindingExampleModel {
        public String myid;
        public String email;

        public String getMyid() {
            return myid;
        }

        public void setMyid(String myid) {
            this.myid = myid;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void itShouldBindForm(){
        Form<FormBindingExampleModel> userForm = form(FormBindingExampleModel.class);

        Map<String,String> anyData = new HashMap();
        anyData.put("my_id", "bob@gmail.com");
        anyData.put("email", "secret");
        FormBindingExampleModel user = userForm.bind(anyData).get();

        System.out.println(user.myid);

        assert(user.myid.equals("bob@gmail.com"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use form's `fill()` method inorder to populate the form with existing value.

```
@Test
public void itShouldBindForm(){
    Form<FormBindingExampleModel> userForm = form(FormBindingExampleModel.class);

    FormBindingExampleModel formModel = new FormBindingExampleModel();

    formModel.setMyid("bob@gmail.com");
    formModel.setEmail("secret");

    userForm.fill(formModel);

    FormBindingExampleModel user = userForm.get();

    System.out.println(user.getMyid);

    assert(user.getMyid.equals("bob@gmail.com"));
}
```

Documentation available [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/api/java/play/data/Form.html).